# How to get spring-boot @Async to work with Java 8

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, java-8

I am trying to call a method asynchronously. But somehow it doesn't work. Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

My main entry point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        AsyncService asyncService = new AsyncService();
        asyncService.asyncMethod();
        asyncService.asyncMethod();
    }

}
```

Async Service:

```
@Component
public class AsyncService {

    @Async
    public void asyncMethod(){

        log.info("starting...");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("ending...");
    }
}
```

And finally, in log I am expecting:

1. starting...
2. starting...
3. ending...
4. ending...

but this is what I get:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2019-02-13 17:52:41.548  INFO 85734 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on mntbden00122972 with PID 85734 (/Users/h3560/demo/target/classes started by h3560 in /Users/h3560/demo)
2019-02-13 17:52:41.550  INFO 85734 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-13 17:52:42.084  INFO 85734 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.76 seconds (JVM running for 1.329)
2019-02-13 17:52:42.086  INFO 85734 --- [           main] com.example.demo.services.AsyncService   : starting...
2019-02-13 17:52:44.088  INFO 85734 --- [           main] com.example.demo.services.AsyncService   : ending...
2019-02-13 17:52:44.089  INFO 85734 --- [           main] com.example.demo.services.AsyncService   : starting...
2019-02-13 17:52:46.091  INFO 85734 --- [           main] com.example.demo.services.AsyncService   : ending...
```

Comment: Do you have a bean of type `Executor` in context?

Comment: Nope, this is a completely virgin demo project from start.spring.io

Comment: Could you create one in one of your configuration files? I am going to type how you do it in an answer, since it won't fit/will look ugly here.

Comment: I am trying to understand why this is not working. If I don't provide my Executor, a simple executor is provided by Spring.

Comment: You could list your beans and see if it's actually in context. I have seen some cases where Spring wouldn't provide the beans it should have. Or it might have defined an executor with 1 as pool size. Worth giving it a shot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Async` is spring's annotation that is being applied to `public` methods on proxies (that's why they need to be public). Self invocation does not work.

In your example, you are not using dependency injection mechanism from spring, so no proxy is being created. To bypass it, you need to make a `@Bean` out of it (which you have done by annotating it with `@Component`) and `@Autowire` it before execution:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class DemoApplication {

@Autowired
AsyncService asyncService;

    public someMethod() {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        asyncService.asyncMethod();
        asyncService.asyncMethod();
    }

}
```

With this spring AOP can wrap the component into proxy and execute the method asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're having is with instantiating the object manually via the `new` operator. This does not give the framework the opportunity to wrap the object in proxies. If you want to use the Asynchronous methods you have to use Spring DI by Factory Methos, `@Autowired` (or `@Inject`) or using XML configurations.

If you do it like that, you can make `System.out.println(obj.getClass())`, to see, that under the hood beans injected with DI are not of the class you used there, but of a proxy one.

Comment: Isn't that just repetition of my answer? Everything is already there.

Comment: Not exactly. The answers were simultaneous.